# How to keep phantomjs webdriver from using up all of my ports

Tags: c#, azure, selenium, phantomjs, port

I am trying to scrape data from a page with infinite scrolling. The page displays the total number of items that could eventually be loaded from the infinite scrolling. Given these needs/environment I used phantomjs's webdriver in a loop to scroll down, grab all the items, and check if we've reached the max yet. Unfortunately my code keeps springing up an error stating

```
Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

From what I can tell, my code is causing all of the ports to be used up in individual requests in a short time, and the ports are not freed up before the 4 minute default time as outlined here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dgorti/2005/09/18/only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocolnetwork-addressport-is-normally-permitted/.

My application needs to be deployed on an Azure web app, and I was unable to find any documentation demonstrating how to make the ports available for reuse immediately on that platform.

My question is how can I make my application either reuse ports so that I don't run out of them, or how to make the ports available for reuse immediately. The offending code is below

```
            var driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
        List<string> links = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(SEARCH_URL);

            var countOfProjects = Convert.ToInt32(driver.FindElementByClassName("count").GetAttribute("innerHTML").ToString().Replace(",", ""));

            var loadMoreDiv = driver.FindElementByClassName("load_more");
            var loadMoreLink = loadMoreDiv.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn--border-gray"));
            loadMoreLink.Click();

            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

            var projects = driver.FindElementsByClassName("project-thumbnail-wrap");
            links = projects.Select(x => x.GetAttribute("href")).ToList();

            js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");

            do
            {
                links.AddRange(driver.FindElementsByClassName("project-thumbnail-wrap").Select(x => x.GetAttribute("href")).ToList());

                links = links.Distinct().ToList();

                js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");

            }
            while (links.Count() < countOfProjects);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to download entire list");
            return links;
        }
        return links;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around that solved the problem for me for now. I removed the call to js.ExecuteScript in my loop. Instead I ran the javascript script that would scroll down continuously, and added a 500 ms sleep to my loop so it updated at the same speed as my javascript. This caused the error to go away but I do not know why calling javascript uses up a port.

If someone discovers the answer I will change my accepted answer.

```
var timeId=setInterval(function(){window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)},500);
```